# Create std::unique_ptr in a loop

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

```
#include <memory>

#include <iostream>

class UniquePtrTest {
 public:
  typedef std::unique_ptr<UniquePtrTest> Ptr;

  UniquePtrTest(const int& id) {
      id_ = id;
  }

  static Ptr CreateNewPtr() {
  static long factory_id = 0;
  std::unique_ptr<UniquePtrTest> newPtr = std::make_unique<UniquePtrTest>(factory_id++);
  return newPtr;
  }

  void PrintId() {
      std::cout << "Id: " << id_ << std::endl;
  }
  void PrintMemLocation() {
      std::cout << "Memory localtion is: " << this << std::endl;
  }

 private:
   int id_;
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto ptr1 = UniquePtrTest::CreateNewPtr();
    auto sptr1 = std::move(ptr1);
    sptr1->PrintId();
    sptr1->PrintMemLocation();
    auto ptr2 = UniquePtrTest::CreateNewPtr();
    auto sptr2 = std::move(ptr2);
    sptr2->PrintId();
    sptr2->PrintMemLocation();

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        auto ptr = UniquePtrTest::CreateNewPtr();
        std::shared_ptr<UniquePtrTest> sptr = std::move(ptr);
        sptr->PrintId(); //2,3,4,5,6
        sptr->PrintMemLocation(); //But memory location are repeated Why????
    }
    return 1;
}
```

UniquePtrTest has a factory method CreateNewPtr() which can create a new UniquePtrTest object and holded by std::unique_ptr.
But in main function, when I call this function in a separated line, there is not issue. But when in for loop, it seems that the newly created object memory location is repeated.I expect they should be in different memory locations because they are different object. See test result:

```
Id: 0
Memory localtion is: 0x55555556ceb0
Id: 1
Memory localtion is: 0x55555556d2e0
Id: 2
Memory localtion is: 0x55555556d300
Id: 3
Memory localtion is: 0x55555556d320
Id: 4
Memory localtion is: 0x55555556d300
Id: 5
Memory localtion is: 0x55555556d320
Id: 6
Memory localtion is: 0x55555556d300
```

So could anyone explain this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Once the object is destroyed the memory location is free to be re-used later in the program or be ignored for the rest of the program. There's no reason that new objects can't exist where other objects used to exist (before being destroyed)

Comment: *"I expect they should be in different memory locations because they are different object."* -- ah, but they exist at different times. The rationale you are probably thinking of involves not having different objects occupy the *same space* at the *same time*. It would be problematic to park two cars in a one-car garage, but it is not a problem to park one car there during the day and a different car there during the night.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!
 I think after 
std::shared_ptr<UniquePtrTest> sptr = std::move(ptr);
the sptr never been used so in the end of current loop the object is destroyed.
Then in the next loop, previously freed memory should be used to create new object. That is why they have the same memory location. So just as you said, at anytime, there is only one object alive. That is not what I expected.